# R How to apply an equation to each row of 4 columns where each column is a parameter in the equation?

Tags: r, matrix, rows, apply, equation

Below is a  3*4 matrix, where 2 columns represent the lat/lon coordinates of one location and the other two are coordinates of a second location. I'm trying to apply the great circle distance formula to each row. I'm pretty sure I should use something in the apply family, but can't figure out how.

```
d=as.data.frame(split(as.data.frame(c( 33.43527 ,-112.01194  ,  37.72139  , -122.22111, -3.78444 , -73.30833 , -12.02667 , -77.12278,37.43555,38.88333,40.97667,28.81528)* pi/180),1:4))
colnames(d)=c('lat','lon','lat2','lon2')
```

This is the equation I would like to be applied to each of the 3 rows:

```
sum(acos(sin(lat) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 -lon)) * 6371)*0.62137
```

The lat, lon, lat2, lon2 represent the column names in matrix d.

The final vector would look like this:

answer= 645.0978, 626.3632, 591.4725

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the `r` row number in your formula?

Comment: Are you sure about your expected answer?

Comment: How can you have a latitude of -122???  I presume you meant `d=matrix(c(33.43527, etc), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)`

Comment: @Andrew Gustar it's in decimal degrees.

Comment: @MKR I fixed d so the answer would be correct. the dim(d) didn't reshape it correctly and it has a *pi/180 conversion to the decimal degrees.

Comment: @Tracy That  makes sense. I'll update answer at some point to match the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mapply` and provide all `4` columns as parameter to the function as:

An option is to write as:

```
mapply(function(lat,lon,lat2,lon2)sum(acos(sin(lat) * sin(lat2) +
         cos(lat) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 -lon)) * 6371)*0.62137, 
       d[,"lat"],d[,"lon"],d[,"lat2"],d[,"lon2"])

#Result: With updated data
#[1] 645.0978 626.3632 591.4725
```

Answer (score 3):

We subset the columns of 'd' with `[` (as it is a `matrix` - for data.frame, `$` can also work), and then do the arithmetic

```
(acos(sin(d[,"lat"]) * sin(d[,"lat2"]) + 
    cos(d[,"lat"]) * cos(d[,"lat2"]) * 
   cos(d[,"lon2"] -d[,"lon"])) * r)*0.62137
#[1]  3153.471 10892.893  6324.854
```

---

This can also be done in a loop with `apply`

```
apply(d, 1, function(x) (acos(sin(x[1]) * sin(x[3]) + 
       cos(x[1]) * cos(x[3]) * cos(x[4] - x[2])) * r)* 0.62137)
#[1]  3153.471 10892.893  6324.854
```

Answer (score 2):

The `with` function would allow you to use the expression:

```
(acos(sin(lat) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 -lon)) * 6371)*0.62137
```

but you would need to transform it the `d`-matrix to a dataframe:

```
 with(data.frame(d), ( acos( sin(lat) * sin(lat2) + 
                             cos(lat) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 -lon) ) * 6371) *
                      0.62137
     ) 
[1]  3153.471 10892.893  6324.854
```

The `sum` should not be used since the `+`, `sin`,`cos`, and `acos` functions are all vectorized but the `sum` function is not. I've tried to rearrange the indentation so the terms are easier to recognize.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. `sum` is not vectorised and even `sum` is not needed with my `mapply` solution.